# Assigned negative value to char in c prints "?" on macOS

Tags: c, xcode, macos, macos-catalina

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  signed char c;          //range of signed char is -128 to 127
  char d;                 //this is basically a signed char, if I am not wrong
  unsigned char e;        //range of unsigned char is 0 to 255
  c = -12;
  d = -12;
  e = 255;

  printf("%c\n", c);
  printf("%c\n", d);
  printf("%c\n", e);
  return 0;
}
```

These all char gets printed as '?'.
Trying to understand why? is it a garbage value or actually a same char assigned to different values? which is highly not possible.

Comment: "//this is basically a signed char, if I am not wrong" You are wrong in the way that you cannot rely on that. It can be signed or unsigned depending on compiler and compiler settings.

Comment: If possible, re-direct output to a file like `a.out > t.bin` and hexdump the file .

Comment: What character do you expect to see after printing? Do these values represent any special printable character in your encoding?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for the first comment that clarifies why "tutorialspoint.com" has given both ranges for 'char'. I didn't understand the second comment, not expecting any character; rather wanted to know what's the logic behind the way program is behaving.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Sorry I didn't understand a word

Comment: If you print some some value that does not represent any printable character, the OS might just show some "garbage" character instead.

Comment: @Gerhardh: got it, According to [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) , 255 has assigned character. For a matter of fact, unsigned char range is 0 to 255, and if I assigned e = 153 in above program; it still prints '?'. When referred to the extended ASCII table it clearly shows that it has some assigned character.

Comment: Try `for (int i = -128; i < 256; i++) printf("%d <%c>\n", i,i);` for insight to what is happening.

Comment: That would require that your terminal uses extended ASCII encoding. I can't tell for Macos but i haven't seen that lately.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char` to `printf`, it is promoted to an `int` value (in normal C implementations, where `char` is narrower than `int`). For a `%c` conversion specification , `printf` converts that `int` to `unsigned char` and writes the resulting character.

When the character is not a printable character of the character set in use, displaying a “?” is a common behavior.

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined, although it remains a distinct type, separate from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`.